# Visual Studio 2019 C++ CodeLens

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, codelens

Is there any way to enable CodeLens for C++? Either through extensions or native VS settings.

It's specifically this feature for C# I'm talking about

[image]

Comment: Read up on the advanced features.  Some features are only available for the C# languages. :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/announcing-codelens-for-c-unit-testing/
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/351131/codelens-for-c.html

This is all official information I can find on the matter. Seems like they added it in C++17, however, it's focused on unit testing.